# Wordpress add attachment media alt to frontend search

Tags: wordpress, search

I'm trying to figure out a way to add the media alt tags to my frontend search.  So far I've found the following, but I haven't been able to figure out how to include the alt tags to the query_set:

```
function attachment_search( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {
       $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'attachment' ) );
       $query->set( 'post_status', array( 'publish', 'inherit' ) );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'attachment_search' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function instead.

```
function attachment_search( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {
       $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'attachment' ) );
       $query->set( 'post_status', array( 'publish', 'inherit' ) );
       $meta_query_args = array(
          array(
            'key' => '_wp_attachment_image_alt',
            'value' => $query->query_vars['s'] = '',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
          )
        );
        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query_args);
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'attachment_search' );
```